# Cannot compile Qt address book example on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have the sample address book project loaded up and it is failing to compile on OSX 10.6.8. Here is the output I am getting:

```
No valid Qt version set. Set one in Preferences 
Error while building project part1
When executing build step ‘QMake’
Canceled build.
```

I click on the Projects tab on the left and I scroll to the “General” section, and I click on “Show Details”. I see the “Qt Version” is set to “Default Qt Version (Qt in PATH)”. I click on the manage button and it shows me that the version it is using is in /usr/bin/qmake. So I got to the terminal and I type “/usr/bin/qmake” and I get the help output. What am I missing?

***Edit: Some additional details:***
I can use the terminal in the project's root directory to run the command 'qmake part1.pro -spec macx-g++ -r' which is defined under the Projects tab in Qt Creator.  It produces no output, which leads me to believe it worked correctly.

I then run the listed make command which is 'make -w'. I receive:

```
make: /Developer/Tools/Qt/uic: No such file or directory
make: *** [ui_addressbook.h] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/Users/jsmaupin/part1'
```

When I check, the Qt directory does not exist under /Developer/Tools.  **However**, there is a directory at /Users/[user directory]/QtSDK, but it does not contain anything named 'uic'.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8842894/563154, it is for Windows but maybe you can adapt the fixes to OSX.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that Qt Creator is already pointing to a valid version of qmake.  I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I asked this a long time ago, but I saw this on my profile and I just wanted to post what my solution was.  The problem stemmed from the Qt installation.  There was an error dialog which I had ignored.

Qt requires XCode's command line tools in order to install on the Mac.  If you open XCode and go to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components, you'll find a list of installable packages.  Click install on Command Line Tools and let it install.

Then, try to install Qt once more.  It should work without any problems.